# Is it possible to "clone" with rsync a folder to another by creating only symbolic links

Tags: rsync, cp

Is it possible to use rsync to "clone" a folder to a new folder but create the new folder tree structure as a symbolic link to the SOURCE.

```
cp -as SOURCE DEST
```

-s, --symbolic-link
              make symbolic links instead of copying

The above command do the trick but it will not remove files that added manually to DEST if i run the cp command again. that why i thought of using using rsync.

any suggestion on how to achieve that?

Comment: Some shell script that lists files on origin and destination, removes duplicates from the list and then erase the extra files from disk?

Answer (score 3):

`rsync` would not create symbolic links but may create hard links for you:

```
$ ls -lR test-source
total 4
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel    0 Oct 22 18:54 a
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel    0 Oct 22 18:54 b
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel    0 Oct 22 18:54 c
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel    0 Oct 22 18:54 d
drwxr-xr-x  2 kk  wheel  512 Oct 22 18:54 dir

test-source/dir:
total 0
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel  0 Oct 22 18:54 e
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel  0 Oct 22 18:54 f
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel  0 Oct 22 18:54 g
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel  0 Oct 22 18:54 h
```

Use the `--link-dest` flag:

```
$ rsync -av --link-dest="$PWD/test-source" test-source/ test-destination/
sending incremental file list
created directory test-destination

sent 191 bytes  received 52 bytes  486.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
```

The destination files are now hard-linked to the source directory (see the `2` in the second column of the `ls -l` output):

```
$ ls -lR test-destination
total 4
-rw-r--r--  2 kk  wheel    0 Oct 22 18:54 a
-rw-r--r--  2 kk  wheel    0 Oct 22 18:54 b
-rw-r--r--  2 kk  wheel    0 Oct 22 18:54 c
-rw-r--r--  2 kk  wheel    0 Oct 22 18:54 d
drwxr-xr-x  2 kk  wheel  512 Oct 22 18:54 dir

test-destination/dir:
total 0
-rw-r--r--  2 kk  wheel  0 Oct 22 18:54 e
-rw-r--r--  2 kk  wheel  0 Oct 22 18:54 f
-rw-r--r--  2 kk  wheel  0 Oct 22 18:54 g
-rw-r--r--  2 kk  wheel  0 Oct 22 18:54 h
```

The link count has also increased on the files in the source directory (obviously):

```
$ ls -lR test-source
total 4
-rw-r--r--  2 kk  wheel    0 Oct 22 18:54 a
-rw-r--r--  2 kk  wheel    0 Oct 22 18:54 b
-rw-r--r--  2 kk  wheel    0 Oct 22 18:54 c
-rw-r--r--  2 kk  wheel    0 Oct 22 18:54 d
drwxr-xr-x  2 kk  wheel  512 Oct 22 18:54 dir

test-source/dir:
total 0
-rw-r--r--  2 kk  wheel  0 Oct 22 18:54 e
-rw-r--r--  2 kk  wheel  0 Oct 22 18:54 f
-rw-r--r--  2 kk  wheel  0 Oct 22 18:54 g
-rw-r--r--  2 kk  wheel  0 Oct 22 18:54 h
```

---

To remove files in the destination directory that does not exist in the source directory, use the `--delete` flag:

```
$ touch test-destination/delete_me

$ rsync -av --delete --link-dest="$PWD/test-source" test-source/ test-destination/
sending incremental file list
deleting delete_me
./

sent 194 bytes  received 29 bytes  446.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
```

Comment: i ‫appreciate your well written  answer . do you think using hard link will be better?

Comment: @AsafMagen "Better"? The only case where it will _not work_ is when the source and destination directories are on two different filesystems (partitions). I can say nothing about whether it would be "better".